# How to put layouts at the four corners and four middles

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a layout that has linearlayouts at all four corners and the four side middles.  I can not get the vertical middle to work.  It covers up the ones on the top.  I am dynamically adding textviews to the linearlayouts to create a list of strings around the edges and sides of the view.

Any help is appreciated?

Here is my layout.xml file.  It looks right in the Design window but not for the actual application.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="elsys.gtri.ehsawearable.VideoPreviewFragment"
    android:background="#ff000000">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TopLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutTopLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutTopCenter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutTopRight"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MiddleLayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutMiddleLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/fd_activity_surface_view"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutMiddleRight"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/BottomLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutBottomLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutBottomCenter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linerLayoutBottomRight"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want a grid like system why not use a TableView?

Comment: what do you want actuallly?? your question is not clear

Comment: I am trying to dynamically add a variable list of TextViews in the four corners and four sides of the main view.  I thought that by placing LinearLayouts at these 8 locations, I would be able to inside the code add and remove textview to display text strings.